# $S_{\Omega}$ is an infinite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

If we want to prove the following statement:

"Prove that if $\Omega=[1,2,3,...]$ then $S_{\Omega}$ is an infinite group."

Since the number of permutations of $S_{n}$ is $n!$,  is it enough to say that since $n$ is infinite, so is $n!$.

I ask this because the book I am reading explicitly states that this is not an acceptable proof, and I do not see why.

Comment: You are over-thinking this.  It is enough to exhibit (construct) an infinite number of group elements.  What is a really easy permutation on $\Omega$?

Comment: You allow $\sigma_{k}$ to be a permutation such that $\sigma_{k}(1)=k$, and each of these permutations are distinct. Since there are an infinite number of k's to choose, there are an infinite number of permutation.

Comment: You could argue that the number of permutations is larger $\ge n!$ for every $n$. So that number is infinite. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your "proof" is unacceptable since $n!$ is only defined for $n$ finite.

To prove that $S_\Omega$ is infinite, you need to exhibit infinitely many elements of $S_\Omega$ - say, one for each natural number $n$. Can you see how to do this? (HINT: don't make it more complicated than necessary . . .)

Comment: I understand how to prove it another way. Its just that I was wondering why this proof was not allowed. Thanks for clearing it up.